# i am not able to update in database using php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i am new to code igniter i am not able to resolve this problem please help me
below code is in

> select.php in model

```
//     update for selected data
public function update_analytics_id1()
    {
    $this->db->where('google_analytics', $id);
    $this->db->update('seo', $data);

}

public function show_all_analytics(){
    $query = $this->db->get('seo');
    $query_result = $query->result();
    return $query_result;
}
//single data fetch
public function show_single_id{
    this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('seo');
    $this->db->where('google_analytics', $data);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;

}
```

> user_authentication.php is controller

```
 public function update(){  
    $id= $this->input->post('did');
    $data = array('a_analytics' =>$this->input->post('analytics') );
    $this->load->model('select');
                  //update query
    $this->select->update_analytics_id1($id,$data);
    $this->show_analytics_id();
}

public function show_analytics_id(){
    $this->load->model('select');
    $id = $this->uri->segment(2);
    $data['seo'] = $this->select->show_all_analytics();
    $data['single_entry'] = $this->select->show_single_id($id);
    $this->load->view('showdata', $data);
}
```

> showdata is my view page

```
 <?php include 'header.php'; ?>

        <!-- Fetching All Details of Selected data From Database And Showing In a Form -->
        <?php foreach ($seo as $single_entrys): ?>
    <div class="form">
        <form action="<?php echo base_url ('User_Authentication/update'); ?>" method="post">
            <input type="text" id="hide" name="did" value="<?php echo $id->id; ?>">
            <label>GOOGLE ANALYTICS</label>
                <textarea name="analytics" id="google">
                   <?php echo $seo->google_analytics; ?>                    
                </textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add">
        </form>  
    </div>
```

*when ever i try to run il get A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: seo

Filename: views/showdata.php

Line Number: 4

Backtrace:*

Comment: Unless you have a variable called `$seo` in `header.php`, your `$seo` variable doesn't exists at the time you try to use it in your `foreach`.

Comment: in header.php i have include only link  [ <li><a href="<?php echo base_url ('User_Authentication/showdata'); ?>">SEO</a></li>]

Comment: Program can't find 'seo'. You must make sure you define this.

Comment: how and where to define seo

Answer (score 0):

### You have to pass data to model function from controller

> Controller code

```
//update query

$this->load->model('select');
$this->select->update_analytics_id1($id,$data);
```

> Select.php (Model)

```
// update for selected student 

    public function update_analytics_id1($id=NULL, $data=NULL)
    {
        $this->db->where('google_analytics', $id);
        $this->db->update('seo', $data);

    }

   public function show_all_analytics()
   {
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("seo");
    $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    if(!empty($query) && isset($query))
    {
        return $query ;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE ;
    }
}

    //single data fetch
    public function show_single_id($data=NULL)
    {
        this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('seo');
        $this->db->where('google_analytics', $data);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();
        return $result;

    }
```

For more help [codeigniter MySQL](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)

Comment: Controller 
calling and sending data to model function 

$this->select->update_analytics_id1($id,$data);

Model function :- 

/* get $id and $data from controller for processing */
public function update_analytics_id1($id=NULL, $data=NULL)
{
    $this->db->where('google_analytics', $id);
    $this->db->update('seo', $data);
}

Comment: i have done say but i got error like this A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: seo

Filename: views/showdata.php

Line Number: 4

Comment: check  and change show_all_analytics() function in model .

Comment: i have got one more error with previous errorA PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/showdata.php

Line Number: 4

Comment: You should check $seo data by using echo "<pre>"; print_r($seo); in view page if it is empty then add  <?php if(!empty($seo)) foreach ($seo as $single_entrys): ?> in view ..